# iOS：How to run framework code only in extension not containing app

Tags: ios, frameworks, ios-extensions

Framework is a good way to share code between Containing App and Extension.

Sometimes I want some code to run only when target is Containing App not Extension, or vice versa.

Is there something like TARGET_OS_EXTENSION ?

Answer (score 0):

use your macro by yourself, just example in [target marcro in ios](http://www.codeworth.com/blog/mobile/ios-distinguish-between-targets-using-pre-processor-targets/)
it is very flexible